# put Asp .net validations to regular html tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how to put a Asp .net validation to regular input tag ?

code:

```
 <input type="text" id="username_Field" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
```

Comment: This answer should be what are you searching for: [your_answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32602372/5953575)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [validate html input in asp.net with MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601026/validate-html-input-in-asp-net-with-mvc)

Comment: As the comments have shown, you're better off doing things the "MVC way". Of course, you can opt not to, but you'll have to do essentially _the same thing_, manually - e.g. use JQuery validation (or cobble your own) client-side and subsequently parse the POSTed data and validate as you deem fit server side.